# Show directory listing/browsing if user is logged in

Tags: login

I am using directory listing on my site. I only want to allow logged in users to have access to the listing and file download.

on my /direct folder I have index.php:

```
<?php
require_once('../wp-load.php');
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
   auth_redirect();
}
?>
```

After verifying that the user is logged in how can I show the directory listing.
I know the directory listing by itself work without index.php. I want to know what programming condition I need to follow to allow logged in user to see/download files after user verification is done.

Thanks